# Why Does Room Delete Operation(With RxJava) Gives UI Thread Error Even Specifying Different Subcribe Thread?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

So simply, the DAO

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Things WHERE someIdOfTheThing IN (:listOfId)")
abstract fun deleteThings(listOfId: MutableList<String>): Maybe<Int>
```

usage,

```
mDisposables.add(mThingsDao
    .deleteThings(listOfId)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
         ...
     }, {
         ...
     })
)
```

and error,

```
// Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

The simple idea i was thinking is to specify `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and then give all the job to Rx's magical hands, but failed.

So what's the thing i'm missing ?

---

After wrapping like below and using `deleteThingsWrapped`, started working. But still don't understand why first approach not worked

```
open fun deleteThingsWrapped(listOfId: MutableList<String>): Maybe<Int> {
    return Maybe.create(object : MaybeOnSubscribe<Int> {
        override fun subscribe(emitter: MaybeEmitter<Int>) {
            emitter.onSuccess(deleteThings(listOfId))
        }
    })
}

@Query("DELETE FROM Things WHERE someIdOfTheThing IN (:listOfId)")
abstract fun deleteThings(listOfId: MutableList<String>): Maybe<Int>
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong about what you have. Maybe it has something to do with what you do in `.subscribe`

Comment: Already the subscribe callback is intended to be fired after it's done. I think its not the actual point that we review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much more interesting question than it seems <3

To solve your problem, we must look at the code generated by Room - for the following:

```
@Transaction
@Query("DELETE FROM plants WHERE id IN (:listOfId)")
abstract fun deleteThings(listOfId: MutableList<String>): Maybe<Int>
```

The generated code is:

> ```
>   @Override
>   public Maybe<Integer> deleteThings(final List<String> listOfId) {
>     StringBuilder _stringBuilder = StringUtil.newStringBuilder();
>     _stringBuilder.append("DELETE FROM plants WHERE id IN (");
>     final int _inputSize = listOfId.size();
>     StringUtil.appendPlaceholders(_stringBuilder, _inputSize);
>     _stringBuilder.append(")");
>     final String _sql = _stringBuilder.toString();
>     SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = __db.compileStatement(_sql);
>     int _argIndex = 1;
>     for (String _item : listOfId) {
>       if (_item == null) {
>         _stmt.bindNull(_argIndex);
>       } else {
>         _stmt.bindString(_argIndex, _item);
>       }
>       _argIndex ++;
>     }
>     return Maybe.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
>       @Override
>       public Integer call() throws Exception {
>         __db.beginTransaction();
>         try {
>           final java.lang.Integer _result = _stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
>           __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
>           return _result;
>         } finally {
>           __db.endTransaction();
>         }
>       }
>     });
>   }
> ```

So we see that the operation itself IS inside a `Maybe.fromCallable` block, which is the part that will be affected by `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. So if the `executeUpdateDelete();` is executed on the background thread, why do you get an exception?

---

See this line:

> ```
> SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = __db.compileStatement(_sql);
> ```

If we check the inside of this method....

> ```
> /**
>  * Wrapper for {@link SupportSQLiteDatabase#compileStatement(String)}.
>  *
>  * @param sql The query to compile.
>  * @return The compiled query.
>  */
> public SupportSQLiteStatement compileStatement(@NonNull String sql) {
>     assertNotMainThread(); // <-- BOOM!
>     return mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().compileStatement(sql);
> }
> ```

So apparently even putting together the query is asserted to not be on the main thread, therefore having a `Maybe` is irrelevant; the block outside of the `Maybe.fromCallable` is executed on the current thread no matter what you do.

---

---

You can solve this by executing the "synchronously executed part" to execute on a background thread, too.

```
mDisposables.add(
    Maybe.defer { 
        mThingsDao.deleteThings(listOfId)
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
       ...
    }, {
       ...
    })
)
```

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in the generator? Why doesn't it put all that stuff into the body of the `fromCallable`? Also if I'd run the generated `Maybe` concurrently from multiple threads at one, will they clash on `_stmt.executeUpdateDelete()` - which breaks the isolation expectation of a cold sequence. Maybe worth reporting this as a bug to Room devs. Btw., there is no need for that convoluted flatMapping; just use `Maybe.defer(() -> mThingsDao
    .deleteThings(listOfId)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())...`

Comment: Yes, I do think it's a bug in the generator. The `Maybe.defer()` is a good idea, I kinda forgot after using `.fromCallable` for everything. I'll revise the post as such.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug, is already fixed and will be released with `2.1.0-alpha05`