# Rxjava2 + Room : get IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I use rxjava and room for below code, but I always get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main
>   thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

```
compositeDisposable.add(dataManager.deleteAllNotes()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                getMvpView()!!.deleteOldDataFromOldUserSuccess()
            }, {
                it.printStackTrace()
            }))

override fun deleteAllNotes(): Completable = mDbHelper.deleteAllNotes()
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check this SO:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729144/why-does-room-delete-operationwith-rxjava-gives-ui-thread-error-even-specifyin

Comment: @Zoe No duplicate, this is combine rxjava and room

Comment: Worth to check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729144/why-does-room-delete-operationwith-rxjava-gives-ui-thread-error-even-specifyin